# JQuery method execution order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the below to load data from a specific `<div>` from a page that contains `<ul><li>` structure into a `<div>` on this page.  What is currently happening is that it "seems" to try and load the menu before the data is there.  I say this because my menu pops up on the page first with a `NULL`, which is the default, and THEN the list I was expecting gets populated into `<div id="hierarchy">` under my empty Fly Out Menu.

I am new to **JQuery** so hopefully this is a simple, ignorant, mistake.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.ms-quickLaunch').replaceWith('<div id="hierarchy" style="border:solid 1px white; width:0px;"></div>');
    });

$(function(){
            $('#hierarchy').load('http://wwcshare/icenter/Pages/wwcMenuContent.aspx #menuContent'); // grab content from another page
            $('#hierarchy').menu({
                    autoShow: true,
                    content: $('#hierarchy').next().html(),
                    backLink: false,
                    crumbDefaultText: ' '
                });         
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) runs asynchronously, you need to call any functions that depend on the content it loads in the `complete` callback, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#hierarchy').load('http://wwcshare/icenter/Pages/wwcMenuContent.aspx #menuContent',
    function() {
      $(this).menu({
        autoShow: true,
        content: $(this).next().html(),
        backLink: false,
        crumbDefaultText: ' '
      });         
   });
});
```

In the callback `this` refers to the element you're loading into, `#hierarchy`, so you can also save on the selector there.

Comment: Not quite working for me.  It now loads the 'list' first then my empty flyout menu....I will keep trying.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Refracted - Should `.menu()` be running on `#hierarchy` or `#menuContent`?

Comment: @Nick Craver: `#hierarchy' ; I could add the code, if that would help.  `.menu()` takes a `<ul><li>` structure.

Comment: @Refracted - I'm not sure you want `.next()` then, sounds like you just want `content: $('#menuContent').html(),` for the menu inside, `.next()` goes to the next sibling

Comment: @Nick Craver: removing the `.next()` helped, it now loads the fly out but it is also loading the static 'list' as well.  Thoughts?  Do I need to combine my `content:` with my `.load()`?

Comment: @Refracted - honestly I'm not sure...where is the plugin you're using? (you have an example page?)

Comment: @Nick Craver: This is STRONGLY based on this here --> http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/

Comment: @Nick: I added a portion, that I hope, is relevant from the `menu` file.

Comment: @Refracted - I don't see where `content` is used in that code, what is the static "list" you're talking about?

Comment: @Nick: The list is simply a collection of `<ul><li>`'s.  That is all it needs to generate the menu.  I see I need to add another portion and will do that now.

Comment: @Nick: I am marking this accepted.  THis resolved my original issue. I don't want to cloud this for possible future goers with my tangent issue.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

1. No need to create two different ready functions
2. If you want to create the menu after the load, you have to put it in the load's callback

   ```
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         $('div.ms-quickLaunch')
            .replaceWith('<div id="hierarchy" style="border:solid 1px white; width:0px;"></div>')
            ;
         jQuery('#hierarchy')
            .load( 'http://wwcshare/icenter/Pages/wwcMenuContent.aspx #menuContent'
                 , function(){ //callback here
                      jQuery(this)
                         .menu({ autoShow         : true
                               , content          : jQuery(this).next().html()
                               , backLink         : false
                               , crumbDefaultText : ' '
                              })
                         ;                             
                      }
                 )
            ;
      });
   ```

---

**Other Notes:**

- It's good practice to use `jQuery` instead of `$`; while `$` is shorter, many frameworks now use it, be proactive and avoid problems later by using `jQuery`
- Also, you should consider posting a more elaborate example at [jsFiddle.net](http://jsFiddle.net) for follow-up help

Comment: You don't need to pass `null` to any of the `$.ajax()` shorthand methods...there are also missing closing braces in your example :)

Comment: "Don't create two different objects" - How does that help him?

Comment: @Ivo: wrong term, again, it was mid-edit.  The answer was still correct.  This solution is actually better than Nick's

Comment: @vol7ron - I'm curious how it's a better solution?  I see a more wasteful selector in there (`this` is already `#hierarchy`, no need to find it again), and formatting that makes it hard to tell what's going on, but missing the advantages here... enlighten me? :)

Comment: @Nick: (1) about `this`, you are correct, I missed that one.  (2) `jQuery` is actually the preferred method, even listed in the docs. `$` is meant for internal use only (3) As for formatting, you are incorrect, you are just not used to it - I said the same thing initially.  When you have many more functions you'll understand why.  I'll add the SO has some spacing problems in the display.

Comment: @vol7ron - I don't know where that came from `$` is perfectly acceptable and **not** for internal use only (ask *any* jQuery developer on this one...you've gotten some really bad information ehre), in fact `$` doesn't work *inside* jQuery core, it isn't defined until the end.  I do have many functions...still don't *prefer* your format that's true (and it is just that, a **preference**), out of all the examples on SO this is the minority format, which means *most* (here at least) don't prefer it either, that was more my point.

Comment: @Nick: valid point.  I went from a more C, block style format, to this more object-indented style about a month or so ago.  It has helped in debugging. It may be acceptable internally, but still the external function should be `jQuery` example: `jQuery(function($){...}); // for DOM ready`

Comment: @vol7ron - I'm not sure where you got that information, but you were either mis-informed, or interpreted it incorrectly, if you know what `$` is (and *most* of the time you do)...or none of his code above would work...it's just fine and much shorter.  If it wasn't shorter/easier, the libraries wouldn't use `$` in the first place.

Comment: @Nick: I got it from several places, from jQuery.com.  In the documentation it's listed all over the place.  I'm sure the `noConflict` page has to mention something, since the main reason is to avoid conflicts with other frameworks.   However, I vaguely remember it being in a tutorial listed on jQuery.com as well.

Comment: @vol7ron - I'd love a link :)

Comment: I think something might be listed on the [noConflict page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), but really, you'll have to look for it if you're curious.  I think in [the first tutorial on jQuery.com](http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/jQueryPluginTutorial_Beginner) there are sections in paragraphs there towards the end of **Internal Definition of a jQuery plugin** which talk about multiple frameworks and the `$` scoping.